# Change UIPickerView body color

Tags: objective-c

Around the picker view there is this gray rect of apple(the picker's body), that i dont like.
I cant find any property to change its color or opacity,to be more gentle.

Any idea ?

I was tried with :

```
 picker1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

It does not clean the **inside** color , or the **outside(body)** color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links should help you:

[how to change the background color in UIPickerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968288/how-to-change-the-background-color-in-uipickerview)

[Change UIPickerView background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965375/change-uipickerview-background)

[Forum Question](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=558988)

[You Can Download Photoshop Templates In This Tutorial](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=761)

Its not possible to programatically do it...

Comment: Thanks i have seen them all, they didnt helped me. i wanted to do that in code. i know the photoshop trick, but i heard apple dont like that, and it can be rejected .