# How to change UIPickerView image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uipickerview

i have a custom horizontal UIPickerView like [this](http://hpics.li/f4160e5)
i want to change the image like [this](http://hpics.li/5c3f633)

and i don't know how to do .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869873/change-uipickerview-body-color

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code, or perhaps Google some tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried this code

```
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:3] setAlpha:0.0]; // this view contains the background so you can change it with your new background
// object at index 4 is your labels or images so they must be shown
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:5] setAlpha:0.0];
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:6] setAlpha:0.0];// this is you indicator , you can add another custom one or hide it as i do

//other views are about shadow in the right and left i set the alpha to 0.0 and i can also remove them
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:7] setAlpha:0.0];
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:8] setAlpha:0.0];
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setAlpha:0.0];
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:1] setAlpha:0.0];
```

and to set the custom image here is the code

```
UIView * viewForPickerView1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self._picker1.frame.size.width, self._picker1.frame.size.height)];
[viewForPickerView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"picker1.png"]]];
[[[self._picker1  subviews] objectAtIndex:2] addSubview:viewForPickerView1];
```

i hope that it will help you