# Custom UIPickerView with Custom Background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, picker

I have created a sample picker-view which will display some details. Setting the Background color using:

```
_pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

doesn't seems to be working . But I wish I could create a picker view like the below image

[image]

What I was trying to do is , the entire PickerView background color should not be white, it should fill with the `UIColor` which I am giving. Is that possible?? How it can be done ??

Comment: you want to change picker selected color or the color of whole bg ?

Comment: I want to change the Whole BG color which is white now. Even the selected color (but let me do the BG first later I will change the selected color too)

Comment: check out the posted link will solve your issue.

Comment: @Perseus: you can check out my answer. and check the last link which is exactly same as you are asking for...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Addition to Nina's answer, below are some of the good custom Picker view controls which will be good to use in terms of performance and customizable.

1. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/cppickerview
2. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/afpickerview
3. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/v8horizontalpickerview (Horizontal PickerView)

Comment: http://heidibrebels.be/blog/archives/2012/custom-uipickerview-selectionindicator This one is really cool!! Thanks for sharing it!!

Comment: definitely... This votes encourage us for helping others... ;-)

Comment: @DShah the heidibrebels.be link is broken

Comment: @Rooky: I believe the author of the website has remove the page. Sorry for  that. Let me remove the link.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a custom picker view that uses a UITableView as it's starting point. Feel free to customize it however you want.

https://github.com/derekju/DjuPickerView

Answer (score 1):

You can change selected color by putting tableview cell in it.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)view;

if( cell == nil ) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [cell setBounds: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width -20 , 44)];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.userNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: No No. This changes the redcolor to the no. of items present in the UIPicker. If I scroll down. At the end , I can see that , white color is coming.I want to change only full BG color of UIPickerView, which is white now.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965375/change-uipickerview-background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968288/how-to-change-the-background-color-in-uipickerview

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to customize a UIPickerView.

You might opt to use it in its default appearance or trying to simulate a UIPickerView using another UIKit component such as UITableView. There are some libs that are using UITableView to simulate a more flexible UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0):

**UIPickerView** has subviews. Assigning an image to a view and adding it to the subview at index 2, would change the background of pickerview.

I had had a same kinda problem :-) See my question here!! [Customize UIPickerView's Skin with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450840/customize-uipickerviews-skin-with-images)

Or you can use **AFPickerView**

Answer (score 0):

The API does not provide a way to change the style and color of selection dialer. You can change only inner view of the picker how u want to design.
As the UIPickerView don't have the UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.

Check out below link will help you out.
[Custom iOS UIDatepicker using UIAppearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844675/custom-ios-uidatepicker-using-uiappearance)