# Custom UIPickerView and UIDatePicker, flatter design

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I'm building a small iPhone iOS 6 app with a lot of custom design, and primarily using `UIAppearance` to apply custom styles.

In the app I would like to use a `UIPickerView` and a `UIPicker` but the style of these elements don't fit into my app, it looks horrible. Today I found a [pick at dribble](http://dribbble.com/shots/991626-What-time?list=users).

I think I need to create a custom UI-Element myself to achieve a look like this.

What would be a good approach to create a `PickerView` myself. I don't ask for a complete code, but for some ideas how to start coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont mind the extra programming work you could look into creating a `UIView` subclass (which is all  `UIPickerView` is after all), and implement the functionality you require from `UIPickerView` yourself with a custom implementation.

Depending on what you are after, you might not need to make your implementation as complex as `UIPickerView`, but I would study the [class reference pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) to see how the class works. I think it would be relatively straightforward to do. The graphical implementation will be the real challenge I would say, but since you are interested in a Flat UI the graphics can be kept minimalistic and it will be just a case of responding to the touch events in the appropriate manner.

If you don't want to get that involved you could always search to see if somebody has already created some classes for public use that implement a Flat UI look!

Answer (score 1):

This is a customizable project
http://dev.doukasd.com/2011/04/infinite-scrolling-dial-control-for-ios/
also look into this post [Custom UIPickerView with Custom Background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426219/custom-uipickerview-with-custom-background-color)