# Can I customize a UIPickerView like this one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm developing an iOS 4.3 app with latest SDK.

I have to customize a `UIPickerView` like this one:

[image]

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's a customizable project http://dev.doukasd.com/2011/04/infinite-scrolling-dial-control-for-ios/ also look into this post [Custom UIPickerView with Custom Background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426219/custom-uipickerview-with-custom-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

Check This answer:

[Custom UIPickerView with Custom Background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426219/custom-uipickerview-with-custom-background-color)

Hope it help.