# UITableView - always select the row in the middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with over 50 rows but only 5 are shown at a time. How can I force the middle row to always be selected?  For example 2,3,4,5,6 are shown, 4 will be selected. 
The user scrolls -> 14,15,16,17,18 , 16 will be selected etc'.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to select like that OR want some fancy overlay over the middle row?

Comment: Come to think of it, both. But the selecting part is what I'm after.

Comment: this is the purpose of UIPickerView I think

Comment: @LithuT.V Sort of, but the `UIPickerView` is VERY limited, ugly design and has a lot of other drawbacks that makes me not want to use it. That's way I prefer to  write something better on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method worked pretty well for me. I had a table view that showed 5 rows at a time, but when I log visibleRows, I always got a count of 7, so I get the index paths for those seven, and select the middle one (index 3):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSArray *vis = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows;
    if (vis.count %2 == 1) {
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:vis[3] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method that is part of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

In here you can check the indexPath.row value, and if it is within your specified range, use cell.selected.

Further information:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Although I recommend you maintain whether or not a cell should be selected within your datasource, rather than hooking into the position of a cell, this way you can check your datasource if a cell should be selected rather than forcing yourself to use a particular index cell for a particular thing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. The question is how can I tell if the index.row I get from it is on top, middle or end of the list

Comment: You shouldn't be using the view to determine what is selected, but your datasource, this becomes trivial is you use a datasource.  In answer to your question, you can get the number of rows in a section from the datasource method numberOfRowsInSection:, from this you can determine whether the current indexPath.row is at the top/middle/bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose is UIPickerView custom i think,

Take a look [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=picker) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426219/custom-uipickerview-with-custom-background-color) will help you